# Best way to Traverse Through an XML Document and Retrive Data From it?

Tags: javascript, xml

How to parse an XML file using **JavaScript** and retrieve data from it like,particular attribute values? which is the Easiest method to traverse through an XML Document?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery for this:

```
var $xml = $('<node attribute="value"><innerNode attribute="otherValue">Text content</innerNode></node>');
$xml.attr('attribute'); // this would return "value"
$xml.find('innerNode').attr('attribute'); // this would return "otherValue"
$xml.find('innerNode').text(); // this would return "Text content"
```